# Работа с памятью

Tags: c++, windows, ассемблер, gcc

Как выделить **неподкачиваемую** память под windows (c/c++/asm), возможно ли это в юзермоде? Как пример: sql server, делающий подобное

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [`VirtualLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366895(VS.85).aspx):

> Привязывает заданный регион в виртуальном адресном пространстве процесса к физической памяти, гарантируя, что последующие операции доступа к памяти не спровоцируют ошибку доступа.

Однако, не стоит злоупотреблять этой возможностью. Ведь каждая заблокированная страница уменьшает объём ОЗУ, доступной другим приложениям. Как следствие, возрастает активность работы с файлом подкачки.

Также стоит проверить, имеет ли данная функция эффект, если вызывающее приложение запущено **не** от имени администратора.

В ремарке написано, что по умолчанию стоят достаточно жёсткие ограничения на объём блокируемой памяти, которые можно снять вызовом функции [`SetProcessWorkingSetSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686234(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Дополнение: под ошибками доступа имеются в виду так называемые «soft page fault» — восстановимые ошибки, обрабатываемые операционной системой на низком уровне. Возникают они, когда при выгрузке физической страницы в файл подкачки она помечается как недоступная. Обращение к таким меченым страницам вызывает исключение, при обработке которого операционная система загружает страницу обратно в ОЗУ.

Comment: Благодарю. Буду пробовать.